# Code do not work in visual studio 2019 Error:0xC0000005

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I can perfectly run this code in Visual studio 2005 and unable to run it in visual studio 2019 getting following error

Exception thrown at 0x0061C1E5 in Mapper.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00B84D50.
shows error in (lpColourTable[(lpBits[0] & 0xF0) >> 4] = dwBackground;)

// Load a bitmap and stuff the background colour into the palette in
place // of the bottom-left colour

```
BOOL LoadBitmap(int nBitmap, CBitmap& bm)
{
    // Get the bitmap memory
    HANDLE hRes = ::FindResource(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(nBitmap), RT_BITMAP);
    if (hRes == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    HANDLE hResMem = ::LoadResource(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), (HRSRC)hRes);
    if (hResMem == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    LPBITMAPINFOHEADER lpBm = (LPBITMAPINFOHEADER)::LockResource(hResMem);
    if (lpBm == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Substitute the bottom-left colour for the window background colour
    // have to shuffle the RGB values around
    DWORD dwBackground = GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW);
    dwBackground = RGB(GetBValue(dwBackground),GetGValue(dwBackground),GetRValue(dwBackground));

    DWORD* lpColourTable = (DWORD*)(lpBm + 1);
    BYTE* lpBits = (BYTE*)(lpColourTable + 16);
    lpColourTable[(lpBits[0] & 0xF0) >> 4] = dwBackground;


    // Now convert it into a device-dependent bitmap
    HDC hDC = ::GetDC(NULL);
    hRes = ::CreateDIBitmap(hDC, lpBm, CBM_INIT, lpBits, (LPBITMAPINFO)lpBm, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    bm.Attach(hRes);
    ::ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: You probably need to add code to check _"...The BITMAPINFOHEADER structure __may be followed__ by an array of palette entries or color masks. The rules depend on the value of biCompression..."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfoheader

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  Set a breakpoint on the line.  Inspect `lpBits` and `lpBits[0]`, inspect `lpColourTable` and `lpColourTable[x]` where x is the result of the expression in the code.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to re-invent the [`LR_LOADTRANSPARENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagew) flag. Why not just use the `LR_LOADTRANSPARENT` flag instead?

Comment: `lpBm` inside resource so in read-only memory. you try write to it

Comment: @RbMm - I am curious how it runs in VS 2005 then?

Comment: @VladFeinstein - i can not say this based only on existing info. need have binary *PE* which "perfectly run this code" and look.